# What kind of storage to use?

Tags: android, storage, android-sqlite

I am making an Attendance Register app on android. It is basically for students to keep a tab on their attendance. The app displays a calendar on which a user can click on a date and mark it as present/absent/other. I was thinking of using SQLite database with two columns: "Date" and "Attendance". Each day would be registered as a new row in the table with the corresponding date and the attendance marked (present/absent/other). Also, there would be a different table for a different subject's attendance.

Can you guys suggest a different or a better way to go around doing it?

Comment: you have already answer your own question. The better way is using a database SQLite .

Comment: How is this question "too broad"? The scenario presented in the question is very precise and the choice of answers is not too many. Also, "answers would be too long for this format"? I am just asking for a way to store data. The answer need not be long - as you can see in the only answer to this question.

Comment: i didn't marked your question ad "too board and i didn't down voted, i've just put my comment about SQLite, and the format of your data etc , it is about how you are concepting your problem ; that's all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good apart from the bit related to having a new table for each subject, which looks kinda clumsy to me. Why not have a single table with 3 colums `SubjectAttendance(date, subject, attendance)`.